# How to fix "Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value" error when function loops

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have an android application I developed, that allows the sign up of users. I wrote a firebase cloud function that triggers when a User is created, to generate a 5-digit random integer value for the user who just signed up and it stores the generated code in firebase real time database in the following structure.

```
MainProject
     |
     |-Codes
         |-UniqueUID_1
                |-code:72834
         |-UniqueUID_2
                |-code:23784
```

The function that I deployed in order to make sure that the code generation is in the backend, is as seen below. There is a value "*checker*" which is initialised as 0. I use this value to determine when to exit the while loop. Basically I want the function to generate a 5-digit random value, then check the real time database if that generated value exists in all entries under "Codes", then if it does not exist, append it to the Codes under the relevant UID. If it exists, *checker* remains zero and the loop continues.

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

var checker = 0;
exports.createUserCode = functions.auth.user().onCreate(event => {

    while (checker == 0){
        var newRand = getUserCode(89999,10000);
        var userObject = {
            uCode : newRand
        };
        //run a db query to strategically check value generated
        return admin.database().ref("Codes/").orderByChild("uCode").equalTo(newRand).once("value",snapshot => {
            if (!snapshot.exists()){
                checker = 1;
                //add uCode into respective uid slot under Codes
                console.log(""+newRand+" : "+event.uid);
                return admin.database().ref('Codes/' + event.uid).set(userObject);

            }else{
                checker = 0;
                console.log("uCode "+newRand+" exists");
                console.log("uCode generation failed for: "+event.uid);
            }
        });
    }
});

function getUserCode(size, add){
    return Math.floor(Math.random()*size+add);
}
```

I tested it and it worked fine. I thought the problem was solved. However, on the 7th to 11th trial, it gave me a *Function returned undefined, expected Promise or value* error. I tried it again after a while, and it generated the code fine. Some one else tested it and it brought the same error.

How can I fix this issue to ensure it always works? Thanks in advance.

Comment: My best guess is a missing return statement in the else branch, in the case a snapshot exists

Comment: @Michiel I'll test that out and see what happens. I was worried the looping is the cause of the issue and i thought the global variable does not have any effect when there are multiple invocations

Answer (score 0):

It's really not clear to me what this function is supposed to do, and the top-level while loop doesn't make sense to me.  However, I can see there are a few things wrong with what this code is doing.

First of all, it's depending on the global state `checker` too heavily.  This value will not be the consistent for all function invocations, because they all won't be running on the same server instance.  Each running server instance will see a different value of `checker`.  Please [watch this video series](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLm9A9rcHb1IkyQUu6QwbjdM) for more information about how Cloud Functions runs code.

Second of all, when `checker` has a value of 1 when the function starts, the function will do exactly what the error message says - it will return undefined.  It should be pretty easy to see how this happens by reading the code.

To fix this, I suggest first coming up with a clear description of what this function is supposed to do when invoked.  Also, I would strongly suggest eliminating dependency on global variables, unless you are absolutely certain you understand what you're doing and the effect they have.

Comment: It is triggered when user is created. It generates a random variable, and is set as an object to be added into database, the _userObject_. Then we return a db query that checks if the generated code exists in the database. If it does, _checker_ is set to 1 and the generated code is added under Codes with the user UID as key. Else the checker is zero and the loop continues. The _checker_ has a value of 0 on start. It turns 1 to stop the execution of the loop, only if no code replica exists

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem a while ago. ESLint won't allow the function to complete because it evaluates whether every part of your code returns a promise. 
From what i can see the first part of the if does return something. Try returning a boolean in the else block.

```
if (!snapshot.exists()){
                checker = 1;
                //add uCode into respective uid slot under Codes
                console.log(""+newRand+" : "+event.uid);
                return admin.database().ref('Codes/' + event.uid).set(userObject);

            }else{
                checker = 0;
                console.log("uCode "+newRand+" exists");
                console.log("uCode generation failed for: "+event.uid);
return false;
            }
```